# How to start /usr/bin/bitcoind on boot?

Tags: boot, startup, bitcoin

I'm trying to get `/usr/bin/bitcoind` to start on boot but without success.

I have this script on `/etc/init/bitcoind.conf`

```
description "bitcoind"

start on filesystem
stop on runlevel [!2345]
oom never
expect daemon
respawn
respawn limit 10 60 # 10 times in 60 seconds

script
user=andre
home=/home/$user
cmd=/usr/bin/bitcoind
pidfile=$home/.bitcoin/bitcoind.pid
# Don't change anything below here unless you know what you're doing
[[ -e $pidfile && ! -d "/proc/$(cat $pidfile)" ]] && rm $pidfile
[[ -e $pidfile && "$(cat /proc/$(cat $pidfile)/cmdline)" != $cmd* ]] && rm $pidfile
exec start-stop-daemon --start -c $user --chdir $home --pidfile $pidfile --starta $cmd -b -m
end script
```

After creating this script I've run the command: `sudo initctl reload-configuration`

When I restart Ubuntu the "bitcoind" does not start. I only can start "bitcoind" running manually the command:

```
sudo start bitcoind
```

Any clues on how to start "bitcoind" on boot?

Comment: I was able to get the bitcoind daemon starting at boot-up using just the `/etc/init/bitcoind.conf` file (a bit modified of course - minor changes relating to my server's environment). It may take up to a minute or longer for the bitcoind daemon to fully start. It has to verify blocks and do other maintenance-related tasks at start-up.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally got things working on an Ubuntu 14.04 server. Here's what the final, working `/etc/init/bitcoind.conf` looks like:

```
description "bitcoind"

start on filesystem
stop on runlevel [!2345]
oom score -500
expect fork
respawn
respawn limit 10 60 # 10 times in 60 seconds

script
    user=bitcoind
    home=/home/$user
    cmd=$home/bin/bitcoind
    pidfile=$home/bitcoind.pid
    # Don't change anything below here unless you know what you're doing
    [[ -e $pidfile && ! -d "/proc/$(cat $pidfile)" ]] && rm $pidfile
    [[ -e $pidfile && "$(cat /proc/$(cat $pidfile)/cmdline)" != $cmd* ]] && rm $pidfile
    exec start-stop-daemon --start -c $user --chdir $home --pidfile $pidfile -m --startas $cmd
end script
```

It was basically just a lot of guess and check work to get this working. Here's the important bit:

```
expect fork
```

Essentially, this is telling upstart how many times the target process will be forked while starting. If you tell it wrong, it'll hang while starting. Read [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#expect-fork) for the specifics on this.

One other, minor change:

```
oom score -500
```

Instead of:

```
oom never
```

Not such a critical change, but after reading about upstart a bit and from seeing a suggestion in a stackoverflow answer, `oom never` should almost never be used. See [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#oom-score) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.

Check the file **/etc/rc.local** with  `cat /etc/rc.local`

You will see something like this

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
```

Then just add this line

```
bitcoind -daemon
```

You can execute bitcoind with the options **-datadir=/path/to/data** or **-conf=/path/to/bitcoin.conf** if you need it.